# Not Able to Configure How to Use Function in Custom jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery

I am trying two write a jquery plugin to track box entering into view and I couldn't figure out how to pass UI value to my plugin and how to use the `topIn()` inside the plugin.

Basically this plugin is mean to create a null callback function `boxTopIn` which is re-usable on the client side

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.boxInView = function(options) {
    var settings = {
      boxTopIn: null
    };

    var options = $.extend(settings, options);

    function topIn(elem) {
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        var screenBot = $(window).height();
        if (($(window).scrollTop() + screenBot) > elemTop) {
          if ($.isFunction(options.onComplete)) {
            options.onComplete.call();
          }
          options.boxTopIn.call();
        }
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);

$('#c').boxInView({
  boxTopIn: function() {
    console.log('Box in View');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call `topIn` function inside `$.fn.boxInView`. Try to add this line after define `topIn` function:

```
topIn(this);
```

The value of `this` in that point will be `$('#c')`, so that should work.